# Updating concurrent collection

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, concurrent-collections

I am working on a multi-thread application, where I load data from external feeds and store them in internal collections.
These collections are updated once per X minutes, by loading all data from the external feeds again.
There is no other adding/removing from these collection, just reading.

Normally I would use locking during the updating, same as everywhere I am accessing the collections.

**Question:**

Do the concurrent collections make my life easier in this case?
Basically I see two approaches

1. Load the data from external feed and then remove the items which are not present anymore, add the missing, and update the changed - I guess this is a good solution with help of concurrent collection (no locking required, right?), but it require too much code from my side.
2. Simply override the old collection object with a new one (e.g. _data = new ConcurentBag(newData). Here I am quite sure that using the concurrent  collections have no advantage at all, am I right? Locking mechanism is required.

Is there out of the box solution I can use, using the concurrent collections? I would not like to reinvent the wheel again.

Comment: it's not very clear what Your question is. You have a collection of objects, and You are looking for a solution that would basically 'merge' - 'main' collection with a 'downloaded' collection. So the questions is basically - how can I merge 2 collections in c# with 1 line of code ? is that right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for concurrent collections the locking mechanism is stored inside the collections, so if you `new` up a collection in place of the old one, that just defeats the purpose. They are mostly used in producer-consumer situations, usually in combination with a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx). If your producer does more than just add data, it makes things a bit more complicated.

The benefit to *not* using concurrent collections is that your locking mechanism no longer depends on the collection - you can have a separate synchronization `object` that you `lock` on, and inside the critical section you're free to assign another instance like you wanted.

To answer your question - I don't know of any out-of-the-box mechanism to do what you want, but I wouldn't call using a simple `lock` statement "reinventing the wheel". That's a bit like saying that using `for` loops is reinventing the wheel. Just have a separate synchronization object alongside your non-concurrent collection.